# double text substituion in GNU Make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

suppose I have source file list like this.

```
SRCS = A/src/A1.c A/src/A2.c B/src/B1.c B/src/B2.c
```

I want objects file list from above list.

```
OBJS = A/obj/A1.o A/obj/A2.o B/obj/B1.o B/obj/B2.o
```

I want to write something like this.

```
OBJS = $(SRCS: %1/src/%2 = %1/obj/%2)
```

But since this feature is not provided in GNU make,
I need to think up workaround. Currently I'm using this.

```
SRCS = $(foreach DIR, A B, $(wildcard $(DIR)/src/*.c))
OBJS = $(foreach DIR, A B, 
         $(addprefix $(DIR)/obj/, 
           $(patsubst %.c, %.o,
             $(notdir $(wildcard $(DIR)/src/*.c))
           )
         )
       )
```

1. remove old dir name
2. do substitution
3. append new dir name

But this way is obviously complicated so I want a better solution.
Anyone know better solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use this:

```
OBJS := $(subst /src/,/obj/,$(SRCS))
```

And then fix the suffix:

```
OBJS := $(patsubst %.c,%.o, $(subst /src/,/obj/,$(SRCS)))
```